# Set style for a div using angular Scope value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a horizontal div to show the percent of some activity. I have one outer div with `width=100%` and one inner div. I have to fill the inner div with background color based on percentage value obtained from the controller, but my problem is that percentage value is in `$scope` variable percentage.

My code is below:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
<div class="innerDiv" style="'width':{{percentage}}"></div>
```

`{{percentage}}` is my scope value. But the above code is not working fine so my need is that, I have to set style for div using scope value.plz help

Comment: try this `ng-style="{'width':percentage}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-style="{'width' : width}`

In your controller:

```
$scope.width = '50%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can work without `ng-style`, but you need to remove the single quote (`'width':{{percentage}}` to `width:{{percentage}}`) and add `px` in the end of your variable.

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.percentage = '20%';
});
```

```css
.outerDiv {
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

.innerDiv {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="outerDiv" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="innerDiv" style="width:{{percentage}}"></div>
</div>
```