# Dynamic update style for Div tag using angular

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic, styles

```
<div id="{{f.divId}}" class="progress_bar_filled"  style="width: 0%;"></div>
```

i need to dynamic update  `style="width:0%"`     by using angular according to dynamic created div id as above `id="{{f.divId}}"` .

i refer to below link  no luck  something missing

[Set style for a div using angular Scope value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923302/set-style-for-a-div-using-angular-scope-value)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If `f.divId` is a integer, try:

```
<div id="{{f.divId}}" 
     class="progress_bar_filled"  
     style="width: {{f.divId}}%;">
```

where `f.divId`:

```
$scope.f = {
   divId: 80
};
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kypc3mhw/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Maxim   no luck   div id=[string]      make dynamic id like div id="pg_"+somekey

Comment: there must be some association of `somekey` with the width right? use that in width. Say `somekey` has `somvalue` then do like -> `{ divId: somekey, divWidth: somevalue}`

Comment: no exactly key for keep unique div  on another button  click need to update style style="width: {{percentage}}%;">